# What happened to FSMountServerVolumeSync in Swift?

Tags: cocoa, swift, xcode6, osx-yosemite

I am trying to find a way to mount a SMB share in a Cocoa app that I am creating however all documentation points to FSMountServerVolumeSync however when I put this into my code I get an error

> 'FSMountServerVolumeSync' is unavailable: APIs deprecated as of OS X 10.9 and earlier are unavailable in Swift

I came across some info on an old alternative - DADiskMount but I don't know if this is a suitable replacement nor how to implement it.

Is there now a Swift way to mount an SMB share that works with the latest version of Swift?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/FSMountServerVolumeSync) you should use NetFSMountURLAsync. There is also NetFSMountURLSync.

Comment: I  saw that too Martin however, even Apple themselves don't have any info on NetFSMountURLAsync, even though it looks like it was introduced in 10.6, but you did make me look a little further into it and I have included NetFS into my project and I can now at least see and add the right functions so thank you for that. Now I can have a play around with it.

Answer (score 4):

So for anyone looking for the answer to this, there seems to be no documentation on this provided by Apple but after much searching I discovered that the NetFS.framework is still very much valid and hopefully supported.

Once I included the NetFS framework into the Swift file and had a play around, everything worked as expected.

```
include Coco
include NetFS    

func mountShare( serverAddress: String, shareName: String, userName: String, password: String) {
    let fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let mountPoint = "/Volumes/".stringByAppendingString(shareName)
    var isDir : ObjCBool = false
    if fm.fileExistsAtPath(mountPoint, isDirectory:&isDir) {
        if isDir {
            unmount(mountPoint, 0)
            println("unmount \(mountPoint)")
        }
    }
    let sharePath = NSURL(string: "\(serverAddress)/\(shareName)")!
    let mounted: Int32 = NetFSMountURLSync(sharePath, nil, userName, self.decodeStr(password), nil, nil, nil)
    if mounted > 0 {
        println("Error: sharePath: \(sharePath) Not Valid")
    } else {
        println("Mounted: \(sharePath)")
    }
}
```